# Is it possible to have boolean comparison and variable assignment on same line in Swift?

Tags: swift

The following throws an error.

```swift
if (
  CommandLine.arguments[1].range(of: ".json$", options: .regularExpression, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil &&
  let _config = loadConfig(CommandLine.arguments[1])
) {
  self.config = _config
} else {
  showAlert("Invalid config file")
  terminate()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible with `if-let` ([here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Statements.html#grammar_if-statement) some more info on if-let):

```
if
    let _ = CommandLine.arguments[1].range(of: ".json$", options: .regularExpression, range: nil, locale: nil),
    let _config = loadConfig(CommandLine.arguments[1])
{
    self.config = _config
}
else
{
    showAlert("Invalid config file")
    terminate()
}
```

So here the difference with your code is that `&&` is replaced with `,` (and brackets `( ... )` are not necessary).

You can also use a `guard-let` ([here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Statements.html#grammar_guard-statement) some more info on guard-let):

```
guard
    let _ = CommandLine.arguments[1].range(of: ".json$", options: .regularExpression, range: nil, locale: nil),
    let _config = loadConfig(CommandLine.arguments[1])
else
{
    showAlert("Invalid config file")
    terminate()
    
    return // Return is needed in guard-let.
}

self.config = _config
```

`guard-let` is especially useful in functions. You can step out of the function if your conditions are not met. Otherwise, your defined `let`/`var`-variables, are available in the function.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen! I need to check if `CommandLine.arguments[1]` is a JSON file first... is that possible?

Comment: I edited my answer, now it first checks if it's valid JSON, then `loadConfig()` is called.

Comment: You can further improve this answer by replacing the != nil comparison with `_ let = ` in both cases. `if _ = CommandLine.arguments[1].range(of: ".json$", options: .regularExpression, range: nil, locale: nil), ...`

Comment: Thanks for helping out Jeroen!

Comment: You're right, @JoakimDanielson, I changed my answer.
Happy I could help, sunknudsen.